# How do I pass browser as a command line parameter when launching tests

Tags: webdriver, protractor

I am trying to run multi-browser testing against Chrome and Firefox. 
I would like to only run one browser at a time. So I would like to pass into  test a command line parameter `--browser chrome` for example and have it only run the chrome browser.

I read somewhere that I could do a `params: {}` section of my protractor.config.js.

So I added the following:

```
params: {
    browser: multiCapabilities.browserName,
},
```

The error that I am getting is below:

```
ReferenceError: multiCapabilities is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/csalisbury/src/helios/protractor.config.js:91:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (/Users/csalisbury/src/helios/node_modules/protractor/built/configParser.js:135:26)
at Object.initFn [as init] (/Users/csalisbury/src/helios/node_modules/protractor/built/launcher.js:93:22)
```

There is a `multiCapabilities` section defined. I also tried this with `capabilities` and got the same message.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Here is my `protractor.config.js`

```
exports.config = {
suites: {
    <test suites go here>
},
baseUrl: baseUrl,
directConnect: false,
allScriptsTimeout: 25 * 1000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 90 * 1000
},
getPageTimeout: 120 * 1000,
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    seleniumAddress: seleniumServer,
    platform: 'ANY',
    version: 'ANY',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', '--lang=en', '--window-size=1680,1050'],
        prefs: {
            'credentials_enable_service': false,
            'profile': {
                'password_manager_enabled': false
            },
            download: {
                prompt_for_download: false,
                directory_upgrade: true,
                default_directory: 'C:\\downloads\\'
            },
        },
    },
    loggingPrefs: { browser: 'SEVERE' }
},
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: ['--safe-mode'],
        binary: '/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'
    },
    seleniumAddress: seleniumServer,
},

framework: 'jasmine2',
onPrepare: function() {
    //Set Up a JUnit XML Reporter - Makes a nice test results area and trend graph in Jenkins
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        savePath: 'report',
        filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
    }));

    //Setup screenshots
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

    browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
},
// Setup the report before any tests start
beforeLaunch: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
},
// Close the report after all tests finish
afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
},
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`browserName` is set using `capabilities` - both for command line and in your config. So to set that with command line, it's just:

```
protractor conf.js --capabilities.browserName='firefox'
```

Values passed from the command line will override what is set in the config, so for example you could leave chrome as the default browser:

```
exports.config = {
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
}
```

And then to override chrome and run firefox, you would just pass in `browserName` as shown above.

Or if you want to avoid command line options and just run each browser sequentially, you can use `multiCapabilities` and limit the number of `maxSessions` allowed.

```
multiCapabilities: [
    { browserName: 'chrome' },
    { browserName: 'firefox' },
],
maxSessions: 1,
```

Source: [protractor config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts)

Comment: So for some reason this is not working. No matter what i have for the browser name parameter, firefox is running. I added my protractor.config to my question

Comment: That's because you have `capabilities` listed twice, so it's only going to use the last one.  It's either `capabilities` with 1 browser or `multiCapabilities` for > 1 browser

Comment: I do not want to run them sequentially. I want to be able to choose which browser from the command line. Is that possible? It has to be right?

Comment: OK I think I know what I am really asking. Can I define a variable something like `var browser = process.env.browserName` and then have the capabilities chosen by what I fill the variable with. For example, if I choose `chrome` via the command line, the capabilities uses the chrome section, or if I choose `firefox` the capabilities use that instead.